# Align buttons in html/css

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to get my buttons aligned in my display. If I try to use `float: right;` nothing happends. Below you can find a screenshot:[image]

So I'm trying to get these buttons all in a row below each other.
I also tried using a table, but that one screws up my design of my hrefs
Here you can find my html:

```
        <div class="LineField"> 
            <p>Axo 800</p>
            <a href="Planning.php?id=1"  class="LineButton">Planning</a>
            <a href="DataAnalyse.php?id=1"  class="LineButton">Data analyse</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="LineField">
            <p>JC-FSX</p>
            <a href="Planning.php?id=2"  class="LineButton">Planning</a>
            <a href="DataAnalyse.php?id=2"  class="LineButton">Data analyse</a>
        </div>
```

etc. etc.

css:

```
        .LineField
        {               
            width: 50%;
            height: 8%;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            padding-top: 5px;   
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            background: #191748;
            border: 0.1em #191748;
            border-radius: 1em;
            color: white;

            /* vertical alignment */
            display: flex;
            align-items:center;     
        }

        .LineField p
        {
            margin-left: 25px;
            margin-right: 25px;
            Font-size: 200%;
        }
        .LineButton
        {
            border-radius: 0.5em;
            width: 30%;
            height: 50%;
            background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c4c4ff);
            margin-left: 3%;
            margin-right: 3%;
            padding-top: 5px;
            color: #191748;
            font-size: 150%;
            font-weight: 500;   
            text-decoration: none;      
        }
```

Comment: Setting a specific width to your p elements will resolve your buttons alignment issue.

Comment: It will be a lot more easier to achieve the desired alignment using the grid system of bootstrap

Comment: @Maqk, ye lol. Thats actually pretty easy. Havent thought about that one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width for the p element like below

```
    .LineField p
    {
        margin-left: 25px;
        margin-right: 25px;
        Font-size: 200%;
        width: 130px;
    }
```

Updated [Code Here](http://codepen.io/femkhan/pen/jWpabx)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the CSS below:

```
.LineField p {
   margin-left: 25px;
   margin-right: 25px;
   Font-size: 200%;

   float: left;
   width: 16%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of LineButton class like below

```
 .LineButton
    {
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        width:50%;
        height: 50%;
        background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c4c4ff);
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 5%;
        color: #191748;
        font-size: 150%;
        font-weight: 500;   
        text-decoration: none;      
    }
```

Please see the updated code below

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Wm6zC/569/)

[image]